# Handle Push Notifications while app is in background (Android/iOS/Ionic Framework)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I want to save incoming Push Notifications in a list, so that the user can view all Notifications and tap on it to get redirected (like in the Facebook app)
Is it possible, to store incoming push notifications, while the app is in background in:
a) iOS
b) Android ?
Or is it only possible to get this list of Notifications by asking the backend for it instead of storing the push notifications directly?